# reset Line_position Attribute of Stream in Prolog

Tags: stream, prolog

I want to reset the position of current stream in Prolog by changing the `line_position` attribute of Position in `stream_property`. How can I do it?

Comment: There is only `set_stream_position/2` to set to a position taken previously.

Comment: Yes and set_stream_position(Stream,Pos) accepts two arguments; first being the Stream handle and second being the Position but how to reset the line_position attribute in the Position property since Position property is in itself a structure.

Comment: You can't in a safe manner. You need to first get it from `stream_property(S, position(P))`

Comment: Yes right, after using stream_property, I got P as " $stream_position(8,1,8,0,0) " where the third attribute is Line_position according to YAp prolog. I was wondering how to change this attribute(from 8 to 7) and set it in new Position using set_stream_position/2 ?

Comment: As I said, that is impossible, that is, extremely unsafe

Comment: It seems you are confusing here terminal i/o with stream i/o.

Comment: Actually, using the prolog code, I was writing to a file a number of predicates, one of which is a list. And since I wrote the clause for each element in the list, each element is succedded with a ',' . So, for the last element entry I can't use the same clause as it will again be succedded the comma and in that case I need to have a new definition of the same clause to have last entry in the list. So, to avoid it, I was wondering to find a way to just delete this last comma by resetting the position on the stream. But it looks like it is not possible!

Comment: Writing a list, that really should be handled by code outputting on char after the other. The best is to use `writeq([a,b,c])`